# curl/wget page and assets from url with specific IP address

Tags: curl, wget

Curl supports the specification of an IP address for a domain similar to the /etc/hosts file:

```
curl --resolve "www.example.com:443:123.123.123.123" https://www.example.com/
```

Wget supports the download of a webpage together with the assets (images, fonts, css etc.):

```
wget --page-requisites https://www.example.com/
```

How can I use both option in one command?

UPDATE: The webserver supports only SNI.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

i don't think wget has anything like curl's `--resolve`, and i know curl doesn't have anything like wget's `--page-requisites`

use a [hosts file redirect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_(file)#Location_in_the_file_system) to emulate --resolve in wget, and delete the hosts file entry when you're done, eg

```
123.123.123.1231 www.example.com
```

(note that 123.123.123.1231 is NOT a valid ipv4 address, but it's the example you supplied, so that's what i used.)

Comment: @user2486134 good thing wget is open source then. i don't think it would be difficult to implement --resolve in wget. are you proficient in C? check https://savannah.gnu.org/git/?group=wget